# How to handle errors occured inside a thread

Tags: c, pthreads

I want to implement a very simple design with pthreads:

[image]

From this image you only need to know that I have one thread that is created with `start()` and is destroyed with `stop()`, and inside the thread, there is a function that loops infinitely until `stop()` is called.

This what I have (mutexes are omitted):

```
int running = 0;
pthread_t thread;

void* fn (){
    while (1){
        if (!running) break;

        if (foo ()){
            //Error, how should I handle it?
            //The main thread is still not waiting with join()
        }
    }

    pthread_exit (0);
}

int start (){
    running = 1;

    if (pthread_create (&thread, 0, fn, 0)){
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int stop (){
    running = 0;

    if (pthread_join (thread, 0)){
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Usage:

```
start ();
//At this point the infinite loop is running

//Let's say that in the second 1 something fails inside the loop
//How can I handle the error if join() is still not called?
sleep (3);

stop ();
```

One solution to this problem is to use a callback. The error is passed to the main thread via a function passed as paramater to the secondary thread. The big problem with this is that I'm converting the program into an asynchronous model, which I'd like to avoid for now.

I can save the error in a global variable and check it when `stop()` is called. More solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure that I understand your problem correctly, but for `pthread_join` your thread must not necessarily be running anymore. It is perfectly legal to join a dead thread. The only constraint is that you can only call join once for any thread.

You should then transfer the information why your thread stop through the return argument of the thread function, that is what it is meant for, and your `stop` thread will receive that through the second parameter of `join`.

Also

- your thread function has an incorrect interface, this leads to undefined behavior. modern ABIs transfer function arguments in registers, and here the two sides may have a different vision of which registers are safe to use
- you only need `pthread_exit` when you return from another function than the thread function itself. a normal `return` would do.